# Cascading drop down using jquery from list in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

In My asp.net application (not MVC, conventional asp.net 4.0).. 
I have a nested list object. The structure is

```
    plantDTO = new PlantDTO();
    plantDTO.LstTuningForks = new List<TuningForkDTO>();
    tuningDTO = new TuningForkDTO();
    tuningDTO.LstModule = new List<ModuleDTO>();
    modDTO = new ModuleDTO();
    modDTO.LstResourceTypes = new List<ResourceTypeDTO>();
    restypeDTO = new ResourceTypeDTO();
    restypeDTO.LstResource = new List<ResourceDTO>();
    resDTO = new ResourceDTO();
    restypeDTO.LstResource.Add(resDTO);
    modDTO.LstResourceTypes.Add(restypeDTO);
    tuningDTO.LstModule.Add(modDTO);
    plantDTO.LstTuningForks.Add(tuningDTO);
```

I have values loaded in all these objects. the values are fetched from database and popuated. the idea is one plant may have multiple tuningfork, one tuningfork may have multiple modules, one module have multiple resource types and so on.. 
Now my requirement is i want to load 5 drop downs for

Plant, tuningfork, module, resourcetype, resource

in a cascading fashion. 
i.e if one plant is selected then only its correponding tuningforks has to be loaded in tuningforks drop down, 
again based on the selected tuningforks the module drop down has to reload with the respective data an so on

> the values are available in the list object and i dont want to hit db
>   again
>
> I require to do it using jquery as i dont want the page to post back
>   on selected index changed.  More over i require to do it without using
>   [web method] attribute in my code behind.. Please let me know how to
>   achieve it..

Comment: I dont know what to try.. since i dont want to use [webmethod] calls to my code behind..

Comment: But **why** don't you want to use web methods?

Comment: because webmethod is static right.. my list object that holds the data is non static.. and i will load it at page load & maintaining it in a session variable...

Comment: A web method can return whatever data you want it to return.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you have requirements not to perform postbacks and not to use web methods. Why the arbitrary requirements? Because otherwise, the [CascadingDropDown](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) from the Ajax Control Toolkit fits your needs.

> CascadingDropDown is an ASP.NET AJAX extender that can be attached to
>   an ASP.NET DropDownList control to get automatic population of a set
>   of DropDownList controls. Each time the selection of one the
>   DropDownList controls changes, the CascadingDropDown makes a call to a
>   specified web service to retrieve the list of values for the next
>   DropDownList in the set.

Answer (score 0):

When the page initially loads, embed the hierarchy in your page's HTML as some form of data structure. Then have JavaScript that populates the drop downs according to the hierarchy, and JavaScript functions that handle the repopulating the other drop downs if there's a change.